# Does clearInterval cause redirect?

Tags: javascript, redirect, clearinterval

I have a live link to a camera image that shows when the mouse hovers over a link. I did not like the server logs filling with GETs of the image being loaded every few seconds because of setInterval.

So I added onmouseover and onmouseout events for setInterval and clearInterval. This does reduce the number of events in the server log. But now each time the event triggers I get a 200 and 301 code.

Before I added the mouse events I was only getting 200 codes from the setInterval.  My question, is there a way to stop the 301 redirects and is it the clearInterval that is causing it?

```js
var hold = null;
document.getElementById("test1").onmouseover = function() {
  mouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("test1").onmouseout = function() {
  mouseOut()
};

function mouseOver() {
  var imgname = document.getElementById('imgfeed').src.split("?");
  hold = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById('imgfeed').src = imgname[0] + "?xrand=" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
  }, 10000);
}

function mouseOut() {
  clearInterval(hold);
}
```

```css
.feedbtn:hover+.livefeed,
.feedbtn:active+.livefeed {
  display: block;
}

.livefeed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="test1">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="feedbtn">LINK</a>
        <div class="livefeed">
          <img src="link to camera image" alt="Feed" id="imgfeed" />
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The response code is mainly controlled by wherever `link to camera image` is pointing. Perhaps the hosters are using it as a hacky way to make sure your browser doesn't cache the live feed. The use of `clearInterval` and `setInterval` have nothing to do with the response headers of the image host.

Comment: why use `setInterval` it is used for getting random image?

Comment: setInterval is used to refresh the image.

Comment: Cory thanks for the help.  The problem was the img src link had www but the server is using a 301 redirect on www links.  Removing the www from the link solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the img src link having www but the server is using a 301 redirect on www links. Removing the www from the link solved the problem